# Can angels smite each other in Supernatural?

Tags: supernatural

I have never seen regular angels smiting each other, although we know Rit Zien could do such thing as a healer angel, all regular angels and even archangels used their blades to kill their brothers (but archangels could effortlessly destroy angels).

Even if extremely powerful demons like Alastair could overpower angels with ease, it seems like angels have lesser weaknesses overall, But i am still wondering:

For example, if Castiel (Seraphim, an extremely high tier angel) would challenge Samandriel (Regular, lower tier angel), would Castiel smite him with his pure powers?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that they can, mainly going on how easily Lucifer was able to kill Cas. Even though Cas has said that only angel blades can kill angels, we've seen otherwise (Leviathan, reapers, etc.) If you want to be technical about it, consider that Seraphim rank higher than archangels in Christian theology, but, then again, I don't know how they match up in the *Supernatural* universe.

Comment: I'm no expert, since my knowledge of Christianity mainly comes from Mike Carey's _Lucifer_, but I don't think that seraphim rank higher that archangels, neither in religion nor in _Supernatural_.

Comment: Seraphim rank is not higher than Archangel though, There is only one Archangel in christian theology, Michael. Archangel the most of powerful meaning chief angel in greek. However Seraphim is the highest rank in other angels, Possibly Lucifer was seraphim in Christian Angeology. In the Supernatural, Archangels are strongest creations in the universe, Only beings stronger then them are 3 nigh-omnipresent entities. They are also chosen and trusted by God, So maybe that's why they can smite anything else, But still, not each other...

Answer (score -1):

I think they cannot smite each other, as they only use angel blades to kill other angels.

Comment: Please add some context on why you believe this answer is correct.